# Get Return-Value from Method that is called by ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, button, actionlistener

In my program, I added `JFileChooser` to pick the attachments:

```
public static String[] filechooser() {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    String[] fileinfo = { selectedFile.getName(), selectedFile.getPath() };

    return fileinfo;
}
```

Now I want the method called by a button press to be something like:

```
 static class Action implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        mainprog.filechooser();
    }
}
```

I know how I assign a Button to execute that `mainprog.filechooser()` by triggering the `ActionListener`, but the `actionPerformed` method is not meant to return anything. Unfortunately, I need the return value for the `FileChooser` method for somethings later in the program.

Is there any better way to assign button to a method, something that provides the possibility of returning something or is there a good way to get the return value from within the `ActionListener`.

Comment: The global variable isn't really good design. How are you going to use the chosen files later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a global variable and assign the return value to that variable.

```
public static String[] response;

static class Action implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        response = mainprog.filechooser();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is a the action that is triggered by the button?

I bet, it is not "Call FileChooser", also not "Choose File".

I assume that it is "Attach File".

So your method `Action.actionPerformed()` will have to update the ticket with the attachment. That means it has to consume the return value of `filechooser()` by itself.

An "Action" models a user activity, not something inside your code; and in this case, it is "Attach File", consisting from the steps "Select the File", "Load the File", "Add the File to the Ticket".